# Brownie build/deployment/map.json lost

Tags: brownie

I deployed a project with brownie and I found out that the map.json file is unfortunately empty , I searched with google and chatgpt about how I can restore or recreate it and I came to the conclusion that it is impossible , due to the reasons I did not find anything in google and chatgpt providing wrong answers(code examples with non-existent functions) ,Is it retrievable? And If not can I interact with my deployed Contract in an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just write it yourself you can find the format in brownie documentation here:

https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/v1.14.2/deploy.html?highlight=map.json#the-deployment-map

You put first the folder number in deployments folder and then the ticker of your token.